# Gimp: How to change layer effects once added? For example change drop shadow values

Tags: gimp, effects

I am on my long way to get totally rid of windows and only use ubuntu.
One major reason to use windows is photoshop, but I am trying to get used to gimp although this is very hard for me with 10 years of photoshop in my mind.

One thing I totally missed when I tried gimp were the layer effects. Just a double click on the layer and here we go in photoshop.

Ok, I found the layer effects plugin and installed the python one, because of the preview function (the live preview is awfully slow, but that is another topic).

**But the main problem is:**

**For example I added a drop shadow effect on a layer. How the hell can I change the properties of the shadow once I added it?** I nearly get mad of trying and searching and not finding a solution.

Let's say I want to change the size of the shadow. Once I added the shadow I got 2 layers. The original one and the shadow one. No matter which of them I select: If I chose the drop shadow effect again, gimp adds a new shadow layer instead of updating the old one.

Deleting the shadow layer and adding a new one is not an option, because if you have more than one shadow in your file, the properties of a new shadow are always the properties you've used with your last shadow.

I'm afraid that this is not working in gimp. Please tell me that my assumption is totally wrong...

Greets, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in GIMP yet.

Preparing the foundations for this is done during the current development cycle, as this requires adding GEGL ops for everything. See http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Roadmap for details.

Comment: Pretty disappointing this isn't done yet, looks like I'll have to fire up photoshop again